# Creating a case insensitive SQLAlchemy query for MS-SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to transfer a program designed for a MySQL database onto a MS-SQL database and I've run into some trouble. I discovered that MySQL does not have case sensitivity by default as MS-SQL has. This has lead to some problems with code similar to that listed below.

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Employees"
    Id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True),
                primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    DisplayName = Column(String(64),
                         nullable=False)
    #more columns

def get_employees(sql_session, param, columns=None, partial_match=True):
    if not columns:
        columns = [Employee.Id, Employee.DisplayName]
    clauses = []

    if partial_match:
        clauses.append(Employee.DisplayName.startswith(param))

    whereclause = and_(*clauses)
    stmt = select(columns, whereclause)
    return sql_session.execute(stmt)
```

I know of the SQL keyword COLLATE but I'm not sure how to implement that, or if it's even the best option to use in this situation. What recommendations would you give to create a case insensitive LIKE query using SQLAlchemy?

- Python 2.7.7
- SQLAlchemy 0.7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit odd, in my experience MS SQL Server is case insensitive by default although you can optionally set it to case sensitive using the database's collation setting.

You can use `COLLATE` with SqlAlchemy (see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.collate)), so you should be able to do (I have not tried this myself):

```
clauses.append(Employee.DisplayName.startswith(collate(param, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')))
```

SQL Server also supports regex-like pattern matching with `LIKE` queries, so alternatively you could make use of this in your param value e.g. `'[vV]alue%'`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solved the problem perfectly with MS-SQL, however it does create a minor problem. Adding the collate breaks compatibility with MySQL due to "Unknown collation". Do you have any recommendations that solves both problems?

Comment: I'm afraid the collation strings are RDBMS specific, so you would need to use something different in MySQL - see the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html)